# How To Remove All Lines Containing Any non-ASCII Characters Using Notepad++ or Emeditor

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editing, notepad

How do I remove all lines containing any non-ASCII keyboard characters?

I tried so many times Regular Expressions codes but none work like it should be
I even tried this code `[^\x00-\x7F]+` but it didn't select all the characters

the idea come on my mind is to use this way ``` [^a-z0-9``~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\|;:'"<>,./?] ``` but still not work because some of this characters didn't get deselected like `\` `/` `|` `{` `}` `[` `]` `$` `#` `^` `(` `)`

1. If a line contains any characters not in the list below, I want to remove remove it or bookmark it

   ```
   0123456789`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\/|;:'"<>,.?
   abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
   ```
2. Simple example: There are more characters like this found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

   ```
   0123456789`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\|;:'"<>,./?
   abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
   ¤©ª«¬¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿÷ÆĲŒœƔƕƋƕ
   ƜƝƢƸƾǅǊǋǽǾǼɁɀȾɎʒəɼʰʲʱʴʳʵʶʷʸˁˀˇˆ˟ˠ
   ˩˧Ͱͱͳʹͼͻͺ͵ͿΏΔΘΞΛΣΠΦΧΨΩΪΫάέήίΰαβδε
   θηκλμξπςρφχψωϊϋϏώϑϐϓϒϔϕϖϠϟϞϝϜϡϢ
   ϤϣϧϫϬϮϯϰϱ₠₡₢₣₤₥₦₧₨₩₪₫€₭₮₯₰₱₲
   ₳₴₵₶₷₸₹₺₻₼₽₾₿⅐⅑⅒⅓⅔⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅛⅜
   ⅝⅞⅟℠℡™℣ℤ℥Ω℧ℨ℩KÅℬℭ℮ℯ⇀⇁ↀↁↂↃↄ
   ⇔⇕⇖⇗⇘⇙⇚⇛⇜⇝⇞⇟⇠⇡⇢⇣⇤⇥⇦⇧⇨⅀⅁⅂⅃⅄ⅅ
   ⅆⅇⅈⅉ⅊⅋⅌⅍ⅎ⅏ⅱⅲⅳⅴⅵⅶⅷⅸⅹⅺⅻⅼⅽ
   ```
3. Expected result:

   ```
   0123456789`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\|;:'"<>,./?
   abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
   ```

Comment: `[^\x00-\x7F]+` works fine for me in Notepad++, it gives the expected result.  What is your version of Npp (here, I have `7.5.1`)? Did you check `Regular expression`?

Comment: Characters that are part of regular expressions (like [,],(,),#,^) need to be escaped. In Notepad++ you usually do this by prefixing them by a backslash. So `[^a-z0-9``~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\|;:'"<>,./?]` would become `[\^a-z0-9``~!@\#\$%^&*\(\)-_=+\[\]{}\|;:'"<>,./?]` (at east).

Comment: @Seth: The caret `^` in first position of the character class means a negation, if you escape it, it means ... a caret also parenthesis, pipe and other characters don't need to be escape but the dash `-` must be escaped as it means a range of characters.

Comment: @Toto Good point about the leading caret but you need to escape the others if you want to match them literally. This might be special for Notepad++ but with the above "simple example" it doesn't work if you don't escape them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[^\x00-\x7F]` works fine, but, if you want to use a long character class like ``` [^a-z0-9``~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\|;:'"<>,./?] ``` you have to escape characters that have a special meaning (ie. `-[]\` and add linebreak `\r`,`\n`.

Your regex becomes:

```
 [^a-z0-9``~!@#$%^&*()\-_=+\[\]{}\\|;:'"<>,./?\r\n]
 #                    ^    ^ ^   ^            ^^^^
```

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: ``` [^a-z0-9``~!@#$%^&*()\-_=+\[\]{}\\|;:'"<>,./?\r\n]+$ ```  But, again, `[^\x00-\x7F]` works fine and is more readable
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Result for given example:**

```
0123456789`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\|;:'"<>,./?
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: Toto Thanks so Much you always give a good answer and helpful and match what the question talk about thanks
and btw i know [^\x00-\x7F] is work fine but not with every single special characters

but the first code u did helped me out to keep only what i want thanks so much helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you are agnostic to the solution and not fixed to Notepad++ you could install bash for Win 10, as I showed here https://superuser.com/a/1252271/715210 (sorry I always come back to your questions with Linux workarounds ;) )

I would have a solution, where you unfortunately also will loose the apostrophe `'`

1. open bash for Windows over start menu
2. Go to the folder, where your file is located with `cd /mnt/c/path/folder` (the drive C: is on /mnt/c)
3. If your file is named *foo.txt*  you could generate a file *bar.txt* with this command:

   `` cat foo.txt | tr -cd '[:alnum:]\n\r~!@#$%^&*()-_=+{}\|;:<>,./?"`' | sed '/^$/d' > bar.txt ``

Explanation of the parts:

`cat foo.txt` outputs the text file and with the pipe `|` the output is redirected to the commande `tr -cd` which removes every char, which is not in the list after betwenn `'...'. Followed by a pipe to`sed`to remove the empty lines. Last but not least with`> bar.txt` we redirect the output to the file *bar.txt*

Thanks to:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20007549/7311363 for the :alnum: tip
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48568/223965 for the apostrophe explanation

Comment: i use only windows 7 and i have no option to use another windows
only windows 2012 that i can use as well

Comment: Ok, then unfortunately I can't help you. If you have physical access to your Computer and you have the possibility to change the boot order, then you could create a USB stick with a live Ubuntu and run that commands with that; see that tutorial https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11577720/remove-lines-that-contain-non-english-ascii-characters-from-a-file

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ this is easy:

1. menu **Search** > **Mark...**
2. Find what: `[^\x00-\x7F]`
   ☑ Mark line
   (•) Regular expression
3. Press **Find All**
4. menu **Search** > **Bookmark** > **Remove bookmarked lines**

Comment: thanks for your trying help but i said in my question that the code [^\x00-\x7F]

don't remove everything that i need because there unknown special characters this code don't read it anyway Toto helped me out thanks for ur trying

Comment: @DeathRival – no problem, for me, all the above steps worked 100%, turning sample #2 into #3. Of course, you can use what you did in accepted answer, but this one is faster and more effective. (I bet you did *not* try the steps above :)